# Can I delete yo-rc.json after project has been generated?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've generated a project with yeoman and now I've a `yo-rc.json`. Can I delete this or does this need to exist for any tasks in the future?

Answer (score 11):

Based on my research on this and after a little think, I think it is safe to delete this file. This is, because you're not really going to re-run yeoman again once a project is setup.